# Create .bat or VBA script to create shortcuts for my movies

Tags: windows, vba, batch-file

I rip all of my movies to my HDD so I can watch them in other rooms, on vacation, etc. The folder structure is `[Movie name]>Video>movie.vob`. I want to create a `.bat` file that will look through all of my movie folders and create shortcuts to all of the `.vob` files in a different folder so that I have a master list of links directly to the movies.

I found [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script) that shows how to make a shortcut via a `.bat` file, but I am unsure how to make a loop (or even if I can) in a `.bat` file that will search 3 folders deep in a hierarchy to find a file.

VBA would also work since I already have an Access database that reads `[Movie name]` and creates a PDF list of the movie titles. I could incorporate the shortcut creation in the pdf creation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code have you tried so far? We can help you by answering specific problems you have with it.

Comment: Use `FOR /R` to iterate through your folder structure.

Comment: [How to create Shortcuts in Windows from the command line](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/12/03/how-to-create-shortcuts-in-windows-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: Just do a search for `*.VOB`, *Ctrl + A* to select all, right click and choose *Copy*, in the folder you want the shortcut, right click and choose *Paste Shortcut*.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30028948/388389