# create shortcut file with complex path target in batch file

Tags: batch-file, shortcut-file

I tried use powershell but does not work. How to create complex a desktop shortcut for two exe file from a batch file  with path target format as below;

C:\ProgramData\RAD\dataset.exe S\W\T 11:20 "C:\Program Files\program\subp\prg.exe"

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56643729/edit) to show us the Powershell commands you've tried and failed with.

Comment: In this, `C:\ProgramData\RAD\dataset.exe S\W\T 11:20 "C:\Program Files\program\subp\prg.exe"` what is the "S\W\T 11:20" for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a shortcut via command-line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028709/how-do-i-create-a-shortcut-via-command-line-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which should create a [desktop-shortcut](/questions/tagged/desktop-shortcut) which matches the target you provided, *(just copy and paste to a new `.cmd` file and double click it)*.

```bat
;@Rundll32 advpack.dll,LaunchINFSection "%~0",,1
;@GoTo :EOF
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
[DefaultInstall]
ProfileItems=AddLnk
[AddLnk]
Name="ComplexShortcut",8,16
CmdLine=16419,RAD,"dataset.exe S\W\T 11:20 """C:\Program Files\program\subp\prg.exe"""
InfoTip="Executing a complex shortcut"
WorkingDir=1
```

I was unable to guess your second target, so you'll have to try your best to modify the solution yourself. I will not be updating this answer to provide further information or to cover things not asked at the time of the initial question.

Comment: @Andre, as a result of your short, non descriptive response, I've just copied and pasted the code from my answer above into a notepad `.cmd` document and ran it as a normal user under Windows Vista, 7 and 10. In all three it worked exactly as written and intended.