# windows - create shortcut to printer with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, printing, windows-10, windows-11

There are [various questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547071/powershell-create-shortcut-to-network-printer) on SO explaining how to create a shortcut to the printer queue of a printer using powershell. They all use a shortcut destination like this: `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n Printername`.

However, the shortcuts created like this do **not** have the right-click options like Scan which are visible when right-clicking the printer on the printer & devices page in the control panel. Right-clicking the printer on the `Devices and Printers` page reveals a `Create Shortcut` option, which creates a shortcut which has the same right-click options as the original item. (Dragging the printer to the desired destination folder works too)

The properties pages of the shortcuts created a) with powershell b) with the `Create shortcut` option also look quite different:
[image]

Thus, my question is: How do I create a shortcut that is equivalent to the shortcut created when using the right-click option `Create Shortcut` on a printer on the `devices and printers page` with powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders) for bringing me onto the right track.

You can achieve it like this:

Get a list of all devices and printers:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$devices_and_printers = $shell.namespace("::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\2\::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}")
$devices_and_printers.items() | select name,path
```

Create shortcut:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$env:userprofile\Desktop\My Printer.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = ($devices_and_printers.items() | where { $_.name -eq "My Printer Name" }).Path
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: This is definitely better than having to all that p/invoking, good job.

Answer (score 1):

The correct shortcut does not point to rundll32.exe, it points to the printer in the [shell namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro). This target is an item id list, not a filesystem path.

I don't know the native way to do this in Powershell. With P/invoke it would be `SHParseDisplayName` + `IShellLink::SetIDList`.

You would probably want to go the reverse way first; on a correct link, get its id list and call `SHGetNameFromIDList(...,SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING,...)`. The returned string would look something like `::{GUIDHERE}\::{ANOTHERGUID}\MyPrinterName`.

Comment: Thank you, the keyword `shell namespace` brought me onto the right track!