# create shortcut using gdscript

Tags: operating-system, godot, gdscript

How do I create a desktop shortcut for a specific file using gdscript
What I mean is that I have a program with the extension .exe and I want to create a shortcut on the desktop automatically using gdscript
It is enough to give me a function that receives the path of the .exe file as input and creates a shortcut for it on the desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Godot does not have this functionality.

---

*Since you say ".exe", I'm assuming this is for Windows.*

I suggest you look up how to create a shortcut from command line (e.g. [How to make a shortcut from CMD?](https://superuser.com/q/392061/95718) or [How do I create a shortcut via command-line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30028709/402022)), and then use [`OS.execute`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-execute) or [`OS.create_process`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-create-process) to run that.

*Note: you are going to get some results about making a [Symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), which is not the same think as a [Shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing)).*

Comment: Thank you. This is a useful idea for executing cmd commands through Godot. It helped me